# #region variance & Confidence Calculation

Tags: c#, variable-assignment, variance

```
// None yet...  
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.ComponentModel;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Drawing;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  
using USBkit;                       //This is for the costomised dll wrapper.
using System.IO;                    //This if for binary file operations. 
using lbrStatistics;                //This is for the statistics library.



namespace USBTL  
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form    
    {    
        int iUSBDevice;                                                  //This is the USB enuminator.
        bool bUSBDeviceStatus = false;                                  //Status of USB device.  
        //bool bWriteFileSet = false;                                    //File pathway is set or not.  
        //bool bWriteTofile = false;                                    //Writting to file.
        bool bflasher = false;
        float[,] fTemperatureData;                                      //Temperature Data array.
        const int iTemperatureDataSize = 128;
        const int iNumberOfChannels = 2;
        float [] fMeanValue;                                            //This array is for the Mean Value.
        float [] fStdDev;                                               //This array is for the standard Deviation.
        float[] fVariance;                                              //This array is for the Variance calculations.
        float[] fConfidence;                                            //This array is for the Confidence calculations.

        float[] fMaxTemperature= new float [2] {30, 30};                //This is the Temperature conversion constand.
        float[] fMaxInputVoltage= new float [2] {255*4/5, 255*4/5};     //This is the Input Range coverage constant.

        enum ChanID {Chan1, Chan2};                                     //Just an enumeration for the Analogue Input Channels.

//Class Form1 constructor.        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

// Form1_Load opens up the USB Device and initialises the data buffer.
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Application is starting!!");         //Just a message on the output window
            fMeanValue = new float [iNumberOfChannels];
            fStdDev = new float [iNumberOfChannels];
            fVariance = new float[iNumberOfChannels];
            fConfidence = new float[iNumberOfChannels];
            for (int y = 0; y < iNumberOfChannels; y++)
            {
                fMeanValue[y] = 0;                                  //Initialise MeanValue
                fStdDev[y] = 0;                                     //Initialise Std Deviation
                fVariance[y] = 0;                                   //Initialise Variance
                fConfidence[y] = 0;                                 //Initialise Confidence
            }


        #region USB interogation code
            //Interogate and find the address of the USB kit.
            for(int Device=0; Device<4; Device++)
            {
                iUSBDevice = USB.OpenDevice(Device);
                if (iUSBDevice != Device)
                {
                    bUSBDeviceStatus = false;
                    stxtUSBStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    stxtUSBStatus.Text = "USB NOT FOUND";
                    Console.WriteLine("USB Device " + Convert.ToString(Device)+ " not found");
                }
                else
                {
                    bUSBDeviceStatus = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("USB Device " + Convert.ToString(Device) +" Found");
                    stxtUSBStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    stxtUSBStatus.Text = "USB "+Convert.ToString(Device)+" OPEN";
                    break;
                } 
            }

         #endregion

        #region Array initialisation Code
            fTemperatureData = new float[iTemperatureDataSize,iNumberOfChannels];
            for(int y=0; y<iNumberOfChannels; y++)
                for (int i = 0; i < fTemperatureData.GetLength(y); i++)
                    fTemperatureData[i,y] = 0; 
        #endregion

        #region If USB device found Enable the timer
            if (bUSBDeviceStatus == true)
            {
                tmrNS.Interval = 200;                           //Timer is running 5 times a second.
                tmrNS.Enabled = true;
            } 
        #endregion

        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Application Terminated");
        }

        private void tmrNS_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            #region flasher
            if (bflasher == false)
            {
                USB.SetAnalogChannel(1);
                bflasher = true;
            }
            else
            {
                USB.ClearAnalogChannel(1);
                bflasher = false;
            }
            #endregion

            #region Reading analogue channels.

            int [] iAnalogueInput = new int [2] {1, 2};

            USB.ReadAllAnalog(ref iAnalogueInput[0], ref iAnalogueInput[1]);
            pltData1.data = (int) ((float) iAnalogueInput[(int)ChanID.Chan1] * fMaxTemperature[(int)ChanID.Chan1]/fMaxInputVoltage[(int)ChanID.Chan1]);
            pltData2.data = (int) ((float) iAnalogueInput[(int)ChanID.Chan2] * fMaxTemperature[(int)ChanID.Chan2]/fMaxInputVoltage[(int)ChanID.Chan2]);
            pbTemp.Value = iAnalogueInput[(int)ChanID.Chan1];
            #endregion

            #region Setup the digital LEDs
            int Channel = (int)ChanID.Chan1;

            int iBitShift =(int) Math.Round(Math.Log(iAnalogueInput[Channel], 2), 0)-1;
            USB.WriteAllDigital(1 << iBitShift);


           #endregion

            #region Array updates.
            for(int y=iNumberOfChannels-1; y>0;y--)
                for (int i = fTemperatureData.GetLength(y)-1; i > 0; i--)
                    fTemperatureData[i,y] = fTemperatureData[i - 1,y];
            for(int y=iNumberOfChannels-1; y>0; y--)
                fTemperatureData[0,y] = (float) iAnalogueInput[y]*fMaxTemperature[y]/fMaxInputVoltage[y];                        
            #endregion

            #region Mean Value Calculation
            for (int y = 0; y < iNumberOfChannels; y++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < fTemperatureData.GetLength(y); i++)
                    fMeanValue[y] += fTemperatureData[i, y];

                fMeanValue[y] =(float) Math.Round(fMeanValue[y]/fTemperatureData.GetLength(y),2);
            }

            #endregion

            #region Standard Deviation Calculation
            for (int y = 0; y < iNumberOfChannels; y++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < fTemperatureData.GetLength(y); i++)
                    fStdDev[y] += (float)Math.Pow((double)(fTemperatureData[i, y] - fMeanValue[y]), 2.0);
                fStdDev[y] = (float) Math.Round((float)Math.Sqrt(fStdDev[y] / (fTemperatureData.GetLength(y) - 1)),2);
            }
            #endregion


            #region Variance Calculation
            //Add here code to calculate the variance
            //fVariance[0]=???
            #endregion

            #region Confidence Calculation
            //Add here code to calculate the Confidence
            //fConfidence[0]=???
            #endregion

            //Add here code to write the Mean value, Standard Deviation, Variance and Confidence in textboxs. Hint use labels to indicate which one is which.
            //Also add code here to call the statistic library functions 

        }

        private void pbTemp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Nothing implemented for this function. 
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (tmrNS.Enabled == true)                              //Stop Timer.
                tmrNS.Enabled = false;
                USB.ClearAllAnalog();
                USB.ClearAllDigital();
                USB.CloseDevice();                                      //Close USB.
                GC.Collect();

        }

        private void pltData1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Nothing implemented for this event. 
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //This is just an example of using the statistics library......
            //These are are all local variables!!!
            float [] fAverageValue = new float [iNumberOfChannels];
            float [] fStandardDeviation = new float [iNumberOfChannels];
            float [] fVariance = new float [iNumberOfChannels];
            float [] fConfidence = new float [iNumberOfChannels];
            for (int y = 0; y < iNumberOfChannels; y++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < fTemperatureData.GetLength(y); i++)                 //This is an example for filling up the data Array
                fTemperatureData[i, y] = 100 + 2 / ((float)i + 1);                      //Generate dummy data
                float[] fSingleDimArray= new float [iTemperatureDataSize];              //A temporary array for converting multidimentional arrays to single arrays.
                                                                                                                            // Array.Copy(fTemperatureData, (int)fTemperatureData.GetLength(128) * y, fSingleDimArray, 0, fTemperatureData.GetLength(y));
                for (int i = 0; i < fTemperatureData.GetLength(y); i++)
                    fSingleDimArray[i] = fTemperatureData[i, y];

                fAverageValue[y] = (float) Math.Round(Statistb.Average(ref fSingleDimArray),1);              //Calculating Average Value
                fStandardDeviation[y] =(float) Math.Round(Statistb.StdDev(ref fSingleDimArray),3);           //Calculating Standard Deviation
                fVariance[y] = (float) Math.Round(Statistb.Variance(ref fSingleDimArray),1);                 //Calculating Variance
                fConfidence[y] = (float) Math.Round(Statistb.Confidence90(ref fSingleDimArray),3);           //Calculating Confidence
                //This is for reporting the calculations to the output window.
                Console.WriteLine("Average"+y.ToString()+"=" + fAverageValue[y].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("SD"+y.ToString()+"=" + fStandardDeviation[y].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Var"+y.ToString()+"=" + fVariance[y].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Conf"+y.ToString()+"=" + fConfidence[y].ToString());
            }
        }

        private void pltData2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Nothing implemented for this event!!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format code with four spaces, or click the `{ }` button.

Comment: Also, please ask a specific question.  We will not write your program for you.

Comment: Are you struggling with the statistics theory or how to go about implementing it? And I think you've over-used regions, at least to my tastes - you don't normally see them used to collapse code inside functions.

Comment: Use comments instead of regions. To have comment, start the line with two slashes, like this: `//this is a comment`

Comment: I written the code as far as I could...now am struggling with both the statistic theory of variance and confidence calculation and how to go about implementing it...I have put serious effect into this to come this far....pls help...

Comment: @Shadow: There's nothing wrong with `#region` statements. What's your beef?

Comment: Hang on - isn't there already code for this in button1_Click using your stats library?

Comment: @Free wrapping three lines in a method with `region`? That's not what they're meant for.

Comment: @Shadow: Yes, some people take these to the extremes. I can't remember where I saw it, but there was one piece of code that must have had more lines of code used for regions than actual work. It was *atrocious*. However, your comment seemed very general as in "Don't use `#region`."

Comment: @Free on second look on my comment you might be right, unfortunately I can't edit it anymore. I meant over using it in such extent.

Answer (score 1):

```
#region Variance Calculation
for (int y = 0; y < iNumberOfChannels; y++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < fTemperatureData.GetLength(y); i++)
        fVariance[y] += (float)Math.Pow((double)(fTemperatureData[i, y] - fMeanValue[y]), 2.0);
    fVariance[y] = (float)(fVariance[y] / (fTemperatureData.GetLength(y) - 1));
}
#endregion
```

What confidence intervals are you interested in?

Comment: Thanks for your response don't know...i've tried 2 get to my tutor....without success---seems 2 be talking about the temperature confidence interval......i forgot that varaince was d square of S.D....smh...help me with the later bit also... that had //Add here code to write the Mean value, Standard Deviation, Variance and Confidence in textboxs.
            //Also add code here to call the statistic library functions 
I would ask him about the confidence interval he want tomorrow..

Comment: if you need to set the value of a TextBox maybe you should just Google it first.  Can't help you with the confidence values unless I know what the question is, sorry if that's not very helpful.

Comment: is this acceptable                                                       #region Confidence Calculation    
            mConfidencelevel =  fMeanValue[0]+(float)( 1.96 *  (double)(fStdDev[0])/(Math.Sqrt(128.0)));        
            textBox3.Text = System.Math.Round(mConfidencelevel,1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();  
            tw.Write(System.Math.Round(mConfidencelevel,1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString());  
            #endregion

Comment: Yeah looks good remember though you need an upper and lower limit. mLowerConfidencelevel = fMeanValue[0]-(float)( 1.96 * (double)(fStdDev[0])/(Math.Sqrt(128.0))); mUpperConfidencelevel = fMeanValue[0]+(float)( 1.96 * (double)(fStdDev[0])/(Math.Sqrt(128.0)));